# Package location does not exist "#13/drop/_PublishedWebsites\demo or deployer user does not have access

Tags: release, tfsbuild, release-management, ms-release-management, tfs-2015

I've configured my release management and connected it to my tfs. Component is also configured but i'm still getting the error. Anyone know how to configure it correctly?

[image: FIG 1]

[image: FIG 2]

Comment: Are you using the XAML build system or the new task-based build system?

Comment: I'm using new web build system.

Comment: How are you specifying the buildDrop location in the build definition?

Comment: With artifact type set to "Server", it's not working. With UNC path it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue. The key is to configure the build drop location exactly. Try to drop the builds in an UNC Path first, once you get assured that all files are being dropped in the right location you'll be able to solve your problem easily.
Also don't forget to check your service user's permissions on the drop folder.

Comment: If artifact type is set to File Share, then release manager is able to pick up the builds from the drop location but if artifact type is set to Server then release manager is not able to pick it up and i get the above error. 

With UNC Path it's working like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

With the new build system, you can publish **multiple** sets of artifacts per build. For Release Management to be able to identify which set of artifacts from the build you're trying to release, you have to disambiguate it somehow.

The way you do this is by naming your component in Release Management after the Artifact you want to pull from.

For example, if you named your artifact "drop", you need to name your component "drop".

Comment: With artifact set the "File Share" its working even if component name doesn't match with artifact name but when i set artifact type to "Server" it's not working even if i name both component and artifact same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for quite a while and here's what did the trick for me:

- In my **Build Definition**, under `Build Defaults`, `Staging Location`, I had previously set to `"Copy build output to the server"`, but then noticed in another Build Definition that it should be set to `"Copy Build Output to the following drop folder (UNC path)"` and there the value of the Build Server `\\server\Releases` shall be entered.

Saving it and running it again, **it worked like a charm!**